# Media kit video current position not worked sometimes as expected. I needed to set duration for set quality chnage

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to keep video continues from its current playback position when changing the quality but media kit has no player.setDataSource(...).

Now I needed to declare duration for loading and sometimes if load takes less time then video start from first position but I want to play video from current position. How I can acheive without fixed duration?

Comment: setQuality({required String url}) async {
    var currentDuration = controller.player.state.position;
    await player.open(Media(url));
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    await player.seek(currentDuration);
  }